# what js code to input for a redirect after a purchase has been made with paypal

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

This is a little over my head, but basically I need to redirect someone after they have made a purchase with paypal from my site back to a specific page on my site.

I am using a plugin and was told to edit the paypal.ipn.php file in lines 27-31 (the line under the 'success' comment.) If anyone feels up to helping me that would be much appreciated!

```
include "includes/header.php";
?>
<div id="index">
<h1><?php echo PP_THANK_H1?></h1>
<?php
switch ($_GET['action']) { 
    case 'success':      // Order was successful...
echo "<p>".PP_THANKYOU."</p>";
break;

case 'cancel':       // Order was canceled...
echo "<p>".PP_CANCEL."</p>";
break;
```

Comment: you should be sending the return url to paypal

Comment: Is that the solution? how do I do that? Sorry I am not a programmer and like I said this is a little over my head. I am good with html and css.

Comment: either learn or hire someone, expecting strangers on the internet to do it for you is a bad idea.

Comment: @Dagon I don't think you have to send anything to PayPal. Probably this is the URL PayPal calls after a purchase have been made. Therefore, a simple redirect will do.

Comment: paypal redirects the user to a url the seller provides (it can be in the settings held by payypal, or set on a case by cases bases for every transaction), if you want them to go to a specific page setting the returnurl variable is the best option. returning every one to one page then redirecting to another based on something is not as efficient as giving the latter url to papal in the first place.

Comment: yes was told a simple js redirect will be all that is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `header()` in PHP but then all output like HTML tags should be removed prior.

Example:

```
<?
include "includes/header.php"; //make sure this file doesn't output anything, else the redirect will give an error

switch ($_GET['action']) { 
    case 'success':      // Order was successful...
    header("Location: www.yoursite.com/redirectothispage.php"); //redirect to this page
    break;

    case 'cancel':       // Order was canceled...
    header("Location: www.yoursite.com/redirectothispageifcancelled.php"); //redirect to this page
    break;
```

If you really do have output in header.php that you can't remove, a meta redirect would be better.

Instead of `header();` you would use this HTML code:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.yoursite.com/redirecttothispage.com" />';
```